# « Apparaître en hologramme » : adéquation et affinité de la préposition, analyse ?

Tags: prépositions, terminologie, grec, transitivité, en

Je lis dans un article que quelqu'un *[apparaît](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/appara%C3%AEtre) [en](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/en/29043?q=en#28919) hologramme* et qu'il *s'est [adressé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/adresser) à un auditoire [par](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/par) hologramme* ([La Presse](http://www.lapresse.ca/techno/201703/24/01-5082198-stephen-hawking-apparait-en-hologramme-a-hong-kong.php)). La préposition en peut introduire une précision sur la composition, la manière, l'état, le lieu etc. La préposition *par* semble plus clairement employée dans le deuxième cas pour indiquer le moyen et éviter que ce soit l'auditoire qui soit en hologramme ; c'est donc fait au moyen d'un [hologramme](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hologramme), à l'origine une image virtuelle, de l'anglais [*hologram*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hologram&allowed_in_frame=0), sur le [grec](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8408291) *holos*, « entier, qui forme un tout » avec *gramma*, « tracé, dessin ». On a aussi d'autres emplois savants avec le préfixe [*holo-*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/holo-).

---

- De quel emploi précis de la préposition *en* s'agit-il dans
  *apparaître en hologramme* ? A-t-on une opinion objectivement motivée sur l'adéquation de l'emploi avec ce dont il s'agit techniquement ou conceptuellement, et la préposition *par* est-elle aussi possible ici ?
- Quels référents, ellipses, éléments morphologiques du nom, comparaisons, locutions etc. guident le
  choix de la préposition ici, ou est-ce seulement le verbe ou à
  quel point le serait-ce et comment ?
- A-t-on l'*holo(-)apparition*, d'autres éléments de vocabulaire technique avec le même ou d'autres préfixes savants ou non, ou des formules avec un adjectif dérivé du nom pour exprimer le phénomène et si oui le(s)quel(s) ?

Comment: Au lieu d'une réponse mieux développée pour l'instant : Je dirais que le choix de *en* dans le premier exemple a le sens de *comme* ou *sous forme de*. Cela aiderait à distinguer cette phrase de l'autre où, comme tu l'as remarqué, l'auditoire n'est pas "*en*" hologramme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Apparaître en hologramme

Equivaut à apparaître *sous forme d'hologramme*. J'aurais tendance à dire : complément circonstanciel de manière dans ce cas (voire de *matière* si on admet cette sous-classification).

Ici, l'hologramme et l'homme sont confondus ; l'hologramme n'est pas perçu comme un intermédiaire qui introduit une distance. C'est bien la personne elle-même qui s'adresse directement à nous.

> Apparaître par hologramme

= apparaître *par le biais/l'intermédiaire d'un hologramme*, donc plutôt un complément de moyen.

Cette tournure semble davantage souligner le moyen technique par lequel la personne se présente à l'auditoire.

L'article d'origine n'emploie d'ailleurs pas exactement *apparaître par hologramme* mais

> s'est **adressé** vendredi à un auditoire hongkongais par hologramme

ce qui renforce l'idée d'un complément de moyen (*s'adresser par téléphone, par le petit écran*).